# When publishing customisations in CRM 2015 error generating UIData occurs

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

Here is the error in full:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, 
>       Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]:
>  
>       Error generating UiDataDetail:
>  
>       <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
>       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
>       <ErrorCode>-2147200969</ErrorCode>
>       <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
>       <Message>Error generating UiData</Message>
>       <Timestamp>2015-12-08T16:11:06.2411313Z</Timestamp>
>       <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
>       <TraceText i:nil="true" />
>       </OrganizationServiceFault>

I have checked various solutions to this error. Solutions I have tried are to restart IIS, Restarted the services SQL and CRM, check any workflows are running

Comment: [Cannot deactivate workflow](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f528a1e-e2ec-4bd5-a0f7-e649f59f61c5/cannot-deactivate-workflow) seems to suggest a referenced plugin or custom workflow is missing.

Comment: thank you I will check that out now.

Answer (score 0):

This was a process working in the background. Deactivate process, still couldn't publish all customizations from the solution top level, but could then export the solution into UAT which actually worked.